# Long array of big structs: prefer heap or stack allocation?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a struct with much data in it:

```
struct myStruct
{
  char name[128], desc[128];
  struct Prm { char p_name[32]; int p_val; } parameter[512];
  char Reserved[256]; 
};
```

The size of the whole struct, as shown in the above example, is 18944 bytes assuming there's no padding; I need 128 of these, that sums up in 2424832 bytes, it's more than 2 Megabytes.

I need to declare this array in the global scope, what's the best way to allocate it? 
Shall I just do `myStruct myData[128];` or declare it as a pointer and initialize with `new[]` then `delete[]` it when the program quits? Or maybe a vector?

Will declaring it as a simple array mess with the stack? How can I be sure that it isn't problematic?

Comment: `Reserved[256];`? There is a type missing. Note: you should not assume no padding is added. Some PCS use 64 bit alignment for 32 bit data types in structs.

Comment: yes, forgot to type it. corrected. that doesn't reply my question, though. padding in my example is not added, I just tested it.

Comment: Yes, indeed it works, I'm just asking whether it is a problem for the stack, since the content of myData would be greater than 2 Mb.

Comment: If you just need a single instance of the array, you might use a global or _Thread_local variable, preferably `static`. Holding it on the stack is a very bad idea actually.

Answer (score 3):

Better option from among your list is `std::vector<>`

Comment: That depends on the circumstances. Just stating "This is better" without knowing all details is plain nonsense. It is an **option**, however.

Answer (score 2):

The risk with large arrays is busting your stack. Global variables are not in the stack, so it's fine.

Comment: "... but in the data segment": Well, only if explicitly initialized (and for some compilers/options only if that is non-zero). Otherwise they are packed into the `.bss`. Main difference is that `.data` uses disk (or whatever) space, while the `.bss` is created at program startup,

Comment: @Olaf I *knew* someone would bite me on this one :p // I can't find the "official" name of the *RAM* segment that contains .bss and .data at runtime.

Comment: At run-time, they are normally packed one after the other (often just from the start, followed by the heap). AFAIK, there is no actual name of that area (RAM has no segments for read/writeable RAM). If you want to name it, I'd just call it global variables, as opposed to _stack_ and _heap_ or any additional area (e.g. on embedded systems). Sorry, to be a bit nit-picky, but that was mostly meant with regard to disk-space. For embedded MCUs, e.g. it is quite a difference if you have the initialization values in flash, or just clear the RAM at startup.

Comment: @Olaf Well, as long as I'm not wasting your time, nitpickery and interesting things to learn are always welcome in my book :)